# Как убрать знак ¶ в NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

Вот пример из программы в NetBeans:

[image: пример из программы]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Нужно снять галку `Show non-printable characters` в меню `View`](http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic45559.html)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]